# Meaning of "your person"

Tags: meaning, phrases, phrase-usage

Please elucidate the meaning of this quote by Immanuel Kant-  "so act as always to treat man, both in your person and that of another, as an end and never solely as a means". What's the meaning of "your person" here.

Comment: "In your person" means yourself.  He's saying, "Treat mankind, including yourself as well as others, as an end and never solely a means."

Comment: Ok thanks. Is it archiac use or still prevalent and valid. It would be great if you could exemplify it in a sentence.

Comment: While Benjamin is right about the meaning of _your person_ on its own, the entire sentence you quote is very strange and does not sound like anything a native speaker of English would ever say. Was it written by a non-native speaker?

Comment: Well, it would be best to know what Kant said in German. That quote is an English translation of an original German phrase, correct?

Comment: Yes right. Its an English translation of German quote of Kant

Comment: In any case, he said *in deiner Person*, which is equivalent to the English phrase about which you asked.

Comment: One use of the phrase in English is to speak of having something _on one's person_, meaning that you are carrying it in your pocket or close to the body in some way.